# gRPC, Go & Cloud Run - How to elegantly handle client authorisation?

Tags: grpc, google-cloud-run, google-iam, grpc-go

We have a gRPC server deployed on a Google Cloud Run instance which we like to access from other Google Cloud environments (GKE and Cloud Run in particular).

We have the following code to get a connection object as well as context with the Bearer token generated from the Google Default Credential flow:

```
import (
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"

    "google.golang.org/api/idtoken"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials"
    grpcMetadata "google.golang.org/grpc/metadata"
)

type ServerConnection struct {
    Conn   *grpc.ClientConn
    Ctx    context.Context
}

// NewServerConnection creates a new gRPC connection and request a Token to be used in the context.
//
// The host should be the domain where the Service is hosted, e.g., my-cloudrun-url-v1-inb33tjqiq-ew.a.run.app
//
// This method also uses the Google Default Credentials workflow.  To run this locally ensure that you have the
// environmental variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = ../key.json set.
//
// Best practise is to create a new connection at global level, which could be used to run many methods.  This avoids
// unnecessary api calls to retrieve the required ID tokens each time a single method is called.
func NewServerConnection(ctx context.Context, host string) (*ServerConnection, error) {

    // Establishes a connection
    var opts []grpc.DialOption
    if host != "" {
        opts = append(opts, grpc.WithAuthority(host+":443"))
    }

    systemRoots, err := x509.SystemCertPool()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    cred := credentials.NewTLS(&tls.Config{
        RootCAs: systemRoots,
    })
    opts = append(opts, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(cred))
    opts = append(opts, grpc.WithPerRPCCredentials())

    conn, err := grpc.Dial(host+":443", opts...)

    // Creates an identity token.
    // A given TokenSource is specific to the audience.
    tokenSource, err := idtoken.NewTokenSource(ctx, "https://"+host)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    token, err := tokenSource.Token()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Add token to gRPC Request.
    ctx = grpcMetadata.AppendToOutgoingContext(ctx, "authorization", "Bearer "+token.AccessToken)

    return &ServerConnection{
        Conn: conn,
        Ctx:  ctx,
    }, nil
}
```

Then using the above:

```
// Declare Globally
var myServer *ServerConnection

func TestNewServerConnection(t *testing.T) {
    // Connects to the server and add token to ctx.
    // In cloud run this is done once, populating the global variable
    ctx := context.Background()
    var err error;
    myServer, _ = NewServerConnection(ctx, "my-cloudrun-url-v1-inb33tjqiq-ew.a.run.app")

    // Now that we have a connection as well as a Context object with the Token 
    // we would like to make many client calls.
    client := pb.NewBookstoreClient(myServer.Conn)
    result, err := client.CreateBook(myServer.Ctx, &pb.Book{})
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error
    }
    // Use result
    _ = result
    
    // ... make more client procedure calls here...
}
```

A few points to highlight:

- The NewServerConnection is based on Google's documentation: [Obtaining an OIDC token for the default service account](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#obtaining_an_oidc_token_for_the_default_service_account) and [Sending gRPC requests with authentication](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/grpc#request-auth)
- We declare the `myServer` object globally and initialise it once.  This is to avoid making unnecessary calls to the underlying meta-data server to retrieve Google Default Credentials, i.e. the Token.  Here is a link on this concept from [Google's Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#performing_lazy_initialization_of_global_variables)
- Once 'initalised' we have a ctx object which contains a bearer token which we then use with each call to any of the client's rpc methods.

Questions:

- Is the above an elegant way to access Cloud Run?
- Currently we have to add the `myServer.Ctx` to all our client procedure calls - is there a way to 'embed' this within the `myServer.Conn`?  Could [WithPerRPCCredentials](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#WithPerRPCCredentials) be of use here?
- How would one handle expired tokens? Default expiry of a token is 1 hour, any client procedure calls made more than 1 hours from the initial instantiation will fail.  Is there an elegant way to 'refresh' or generate a new token?

Hope this all makes sense!  Cloudrun, gRPC and IAM to manage access is potentially a really elegant setup when running services on Google Cloud.

Comment: Hello, I came across these articles [gRPC Auth with GCR](https://medium.com/google-cloud/grpc-authentication-with-cloud-run-72e4d6c44739), [Cloud Run with gRPC](https://ahmet.im/blog/grpc-auth-cloud-run/) , [OpenID tokens with GCR](https://medium.com/google-cloud/grpc-authentication-with-google-openid-connect-tokens-812ceb3e5c41), which you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something fairly elegant.  It uses the Google Application Credentials and attaches a `NewTokenSource` object to the gRPC connection object.  My understanding is that this will allow for token refreshes automatically, if needed, at each gRPC Call.

```
// NewServerConnection creates a new gRPC connection.
//
// The host should be the domain where the Cloud Run Service is hosted
//
// This method also uses the Google Default Credentials workflow.  To run this locally ensure that you have the
// environmental variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = ../key.json set.
//
// Best practise is to create a new connection at global level, which could be used to run many methods.  This avoids
// unnecessary api calls to retrieve the required ID tokens each time a single method is called.
func NewServerConnection(ctx context.Context, host string) (*grpc.ClientConn, error) {

    // Creates an identity token.
    // With a global TokenSource tokens would be reused and auto-refreshed at need.
    // A given TokenSource is specific to the audience.
    tokenSource, err := idtoken.NewTokenSource(ctx, "https://"+host)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, status.Errorf(
            codes.Unauthenticated,
            "NewTokenSource: %s", err,
        )
    }

    // Establishes a connection
    var opts []grpc.DialOption
    if host != "" {
        opts = append(opts, grpc.WithAuthority(host+":443"))
    }

    systemRoots, err := x509.SystemCertPool()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    cred := credentials.NewTLS(&tls.Config{
        RootCAs: systemRoots,
    })
    opts = append(opts, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(cred))
    opts = append(opts, grpc.WithPerRPCCredentials(grpcTokenSource{
        TokenSource: oauth.TokenSource{
            tokenSource,
        },
    }))

    conn, err := grpc.Dial(host+":443", opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, status.Errorf(
            codes.Unauthenticated,
            "grpc.Dail: %s", err,
        )
    }

    return conn, nil
}
```

Which could be used as follows:

```
import (
    "context"

    pb "path-to-your-protos"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

func ExampleNewServerConnection() {

    // Creates the connection and Authorise using default credentials.
    var err error
    var myConn *grpc.ClientConn
    myConn, err = NewServerConnection(context.Background(), "cloudrun-url-...-.app")
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error
    }

    // Create a client from the server connection.
    client := pb.NewServicesClient(myConn)

    // Once the connection is created and tokens retrieved, make one or more calls to the respective methods.
    result1, err := client.CreateBook(context.Background(), &pb.Book{})
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error
    }
    // Use the result
    _ = result1

    // Another call
    result2, err := client.CreateBook(context.Background(), &pb.Book{})
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error
    }

    // Use the result
    _ = result2
}
```